# Display of short contacts with Avogadro

Tags: molecular-structure, software

For a small group of small organic molecules, I would like to use [Avogadro](http://avogadro.cc/) to display short intermolecular contacts directing their packing patterns; separately from normal Hydrogen bonding pattern.  For example, to indicate intermolecular C(aryl)-H interactions.

It is known to me that this may be achieved with the freely accessible software [Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/mercury/) by the CCSD (described [here](http://scripts.iucr.org/cgi-bin/paper?ks5091)), too.  Yet, both for the sake of consistency with other drawings already prepared, as well some curiosity if Avogadro equally may provide this, I whish to address the question here.  The sole contribution in the software's mailing list partially relevant to this topic ([here](https://sourceforge.net/p/avogadro/mailman/message/31248417/)), dating back 2013, exludes even the indication of non-classical H-bonds.

To solve this problem, both the "classical version" (currently 1.2.0), as well as the more recent version Avogadro² (1.90.0) were accessed.

Comment: So, what's the question? How to represent an interaction between any two atoms of your choice?

Comment: It's a good feature suggestion, but it's not implemented in either version at the moment. I'd suggest, for example, suggesting the feature [here for Avogadro v1.x](https://github.com/cryos/avogadro/issues) or [here for Avo2](https://github.com/openchemistry/avogadrolibs).

Comment: And as you seem to know, there's a mailing list and a [discussion board](https://discuss.avogadro.cc/) specifically for Avogadro questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the Avogadro discussion forum.